# How to Inline SVG?

Tags: html, svg, inline

I'm trying to add inline SVG to an HTML file, but it doesn't show anything, while it's fine if separate. Why?

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
            xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
            width="16px" height="16px">

            <defs>
              <linearGradient id="lg1">
                <stop style="stop-color:#ffffff;stop-opacity:0.50;" offset="0"/>
                <stop style="stop-color:#00ff00;stop-opacity:0.75;" offset="1"/>
              </linearGradient>
              <linearGradient xlink:href="#lg1" id="lg2"
                x1="0" y1="0" x2="16" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" />
            </defs>
            <g>
              <rect style="fill:url(#lg2);fill-opacity:1" id="rect3001"
                width="48" height="48" x="0" y="0" />
            </g>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what browser?  works fine for me in FF4

Comment: Whoa, really? I'm testing it with IE 9.

Comment: Did you add `<!DOCTYPE html>` ? Maybe IE9 requires it.

Comment: @SB: WHOA it shows now! :D (But it's kinda big...)

Comment: You've given me a reason to DL IE9.  I imagine it is way behind FF and Chrome though. The SVG is pretty small in those.

Comment: @SB: Hahaha nice. :) I don't actually use IE 9 myself for surfing, but I use it for opening HTML files.

Comment: I had a different problem: I had saved the .svg file in inkscape as an "Inkscape SVG" file. The SVG had `inkscape:attr` and `sodipodi:attr` namespaced attributes, and IE9+IE11 refused to show any of the SVG. `s/inkscape:/inkscape_/g; s/sodipodi:/sodipodi-/g;` (or save as "Plain SVG" from Inkscape) and they displayed fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `<!DOCTYPE html>` - looks like IE9 requires it, but FF and Chrome didn't.

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, use XHTML.

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">